# How to make TelephonyManager listen to original call state?

Tags: android

I'm doing a phone dialer and I use Receiver and intent-filter in Android Manifest.In Receiver I make TelephonyManager listen to my call states. My question is that: How and where(in Receiver or somewhere else) can I make TelephonyManager to listen original call state?

My Receiver in Android Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.SetAndGet.amadey.myapplication5.MyReceiver2" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Point_1","onReceive");
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if(state==0){context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MyActivity.class));
                }else if(state==2){context.stopService(new Intent(context,MyService.class));
                }else if(state==1){context.stopService(new Intent(context,MyService.class));}
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```